# Access denied error to .pdb files when building .netcore project in VS2017RC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

**Environment:**

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 RC

Version 15.0.26206.0 D15REL

Microsoft .NET Framework

Version 4.6.01586

**Error:**

error CS2012: Cannot open [file.pdb] for writing -- 'Access to path [path to pdb file] is denied'.

**Description:**

I am building a .netcore application for .net core 1.1 with other libraries targeting .netstandard1.6. When I build the project I get above error. I cannot clean/build or run the project when it is in this state. Does not happen the first time the project is open, it seems very random, because it may work a few times before I get the error.

When I navigate to it via explorer I also cannot delete the .pdb file nor the parent folder which is  either the netcore1.0 or netstandard1.6 folders in in the Debug directories. I cannot even change the permissions on the files or folders. I am an administrator on the pc.

When I close Visual Studio and open it again all is fine and I can build again, which is not an answer.

[Link to my question on the Visual Studio forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ce514cbf-2c2f-4ae2-ace8-fbeaee115987/error-cs2012-cannot-open-filepdb-for-writing-access-to-path-path-to-pdb-file-is-denied?forum=msbuild).

Thanks

Comment: There are 1-2 minutes delay while VS was still building your project/solution, and hence you were not allowed to delete these files. For this issue could you please try to delete the contentious files from bin folder and rebuilding the project(close VS before doing this)? and check the parent folder of .pdb file is NOT Read-Only on folder setting. Besides, this issue seems like this file is used by another process, you can try to use process monitor to check it.

Comment: Thanks @Leo-MSFT. When VS is closed I can delete these files yes. I think the issue here is more why it can't build because of a locking issue if VS is holding that lock? Why can I delete it when VS is closed but VS can't build the project? I have not encountered this in previous versions of VS/ normal C# projects. I'm not sure what is causing this issue, whether it is VS or MSBuild.

Comment: It`s very difficult to figure out the root of Visual Studio can not open the [file.pdb] for writing. Because this issue occurs randomly and could not be reproduced by us. Due to this error, Visual studio can not complete the build process, then it will keep this lock. Besides, Is this problem solved according to the above comment? Is this error still happening after you delete file.pdb?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT This is what I found is happening: I used Process Explorer to find out what is holding on to the .pdb file. It turns out there is a process called **ServiceHub.DataWarehouseHost.exe** that has a handle on the file. When I kill that handle then the build works again. The problem is you have to kill each handle and if you have multiple projects in the solution it takes a while. Currently the best approach is to close and open VS, which should not be the case. But to your question, once I close VS I can delete the pdb file and yes then all is ok again

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Since this issue has be resolved, I will transform the commets to answer. If you agree with it, you can mark it answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem, If not, you can add the comment below, I will keep follow up. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is more relate to the Visual Studio could not write the [file.pdb] files when Visual Studio executed the build operation. Due to this issue, Visual Studio could not complete the build process, then it will keep this file lock. So you could not clean/build or run the project and also could not delete the .pdb file nor the parent folder when it is in this state.

It`s very difficult to figure out the root of Visual Studio can not open the [file.pdb] for writing. Because this issue occurs randomly and could not be reproduced by us. But you can try to **close Visual Studio, then delete the [file.pdb] file and rebuilding the project**.

**Note that**:Thanks for Jean Roux`s contribution, he used Process Explorer to find out the process called ServiceHub.DataWarehouseHost.exe that has a handle on the file. Kill that handle then the build works again.

Comment: That's an answer?!?  We shouldn't have to manually kill a process or restart Visual Studio to build something more than once.

Comment: I do not understand the vote down, since this issue is very random, and after close the Visual Studio and clean the pdb file, this issue no longer happens.

Comment: I had the same issue while I have opened two instance of visual studio and one was running and attached to  iisExpress. While I am trying to build the other (both solutions are under same root folder) I had the same issue. While I stopped debugging and tried resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I've been dealing with this issue for a while, the cause for me was having multiple instances of VS2017 open with different solutions and one or more of them running.

My fix is to simply not have any instance of VS running in debug while trying to build the solution that has this issue.

I assume another instance has the file locked for some reason while it's running.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution that's not really a good solution:

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General, uncheck "Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging"

Hard to know if it's going to happen again or not, but I've debugged/rebuilt about 10 times in a row now which is about 9 times more than I could before. Still a pretty sad state of affairs that a useful feature has to be turned off in order to have a reliable debug/build cycle.

Comment: Hi jdc, thanks, I tried this and it worked, quite happy to do this as I don't really need the live debugging always. This is much less of a pain than restarting the solution every time.

Answer (score 3):

To quote a Mr Aaron Robinson on the Visual Studio Developer Community pages [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/16173/build-fails-because-some-files-are-locked-by-anoth.html) (written on 11. March 2017), this seems to be a known issue:

> This is a known issue VS 2017 when targeting .NET Core projects for CPU profiling (during debugging or Profiling (Alt+F2)). This will be addressed in an upcoming release. The workaround is to either:
>
> A) Not enable CPU profiling (during F5 or Alt+F2) for .Net Core projects
>
> B) Change the PDB format in the project properties from Portable PDB to PDB Full
>
> Note that this should only impact projects that can output a Portable PDB format.
>
> Aaron

I tried B myself and first changed the PDB format to full on just my test project, and got an error where VS 2017 couldn't find my tests and then changed the PDB format for the project I was testing as well and this fixed the issue. Haven't tested A.

To change the PDB format go to **Properties** for your projects, go to the **Build** tab and click the **Advanced** button in the bottom right corner. There you get a dropdown with the **Full** option. (under *Output -> Debugging information* headers)

Comment: Thanks for the update Torfi. Nice to know it is an issue that will be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed with the 15.2 update, follow the Notifications area and you will find all the available updates.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25390/warning-msb3026-could-not-copy-objdebugnetcoreapp1.html

Comment: Thanks Ariel. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to even delete the .pdb file manually after closing VS, check that you don't have another instance of VS debugging a solution that references the one you're trying to build (not necessarily directly, it may be through a NuGet package as was my case).

It's nice that VS "automagically" looks for .pdb files so you can debug issues in other solutions but this seems to be an unpleasant side effect.